# Unable to locate element selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the following website: https://www.bancosantander.es/es/particulares/prestamos/prestamo-coche/simulador

What I'm trying to do:

Simulate the amount and duration by moving the slider. I'm trying to locate them with my webdriver.

But I can't, in fact I'm starting to scraping.

The error that appears is as follows:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  if sys.path[0] == '':

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-29-f71d54453a68> in <module>()
     20     pass
     21 webdriver.save_screenshot('sreenshot0.png')
---> 22 webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='res r1']")
     23 
     24 webdriver.save_screenshot('sreenshot0.png')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    392             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    393         """
--> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    395 
    396     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='res r1']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.121,platform=Linux 4.14.79+ x86_64)
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=4400x2200')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
webdriver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.bancosantander.es/es/particulares/prestamos/prestamo-coche/simulador"
webdriver.get(url)

try:
    webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"_W034_Cookie_Directive_WAR_W034_Cookie_Directiveportlet_.hidePortlet()\"]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
webdriver.save_screenshot('sreenshot0.png')
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='res r1']")

webdriver.save_screenshot('sreenshot0.png')
```

Comment: Your xpath `find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='res r1']")` is incorrect. So, please mention the html of the element which you are trying to find using this xpath

Comment: Also, post your error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following for entering your values

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://simuladores.bancosantander.es/SantanderES/loansimulatorweb.aspx?por=webpublica&prv=publico&m=100&cta=1&ls=0#/t0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

amount =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#amount")))
amount.clear()
amount.send_keys(6000)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return jQuery.active') == 0)

term =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#term")))
term.clear()
term.send_keys('60 meses')
term.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
currentCuota = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.r1 span').text
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return jQuery.active') == 0)
while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.r1 span').text == currentCuota:
    continue

print('Tu cuota mensual: ' + driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.r1 span').text)
```

Comment: was this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, you're genius. Thanks so much.

Comment: How do I select different projects?

Comment: Hiya, didn't you ask a different question already about different projects? Or am I recalling incorrectly?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: You cannot select different projects off this link as it is the iframe src. Instead, use the original url and switch to and from the iframe. You would have to switch back to outside the iframe to make your project selections.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834542/6241235

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is not working due to the space in the class name.  Not sure if that's the only issue but is a problem.  The following line should find your element if that class name is correct.

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.res.r1')
```