# How to click on the list of the <a> elements in an <ul> and <li> elements with selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping a [website](https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/financiacion-coche.html). I'm trying to click on a link under `<li>` but it throws `NoSuchElementException` exception.

And the links I want to click:

[image]

I'm using below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=5000x2500')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/financiacion-coche.html"
webdriver.get(url)
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btncerrar"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Préstamo Coche Nuevo').click()
webdriver.save_screenshot('test1.png')
```

The error I got:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
>   # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> <ipython-input-44-f6608be53ab3> in <module>()
>      13 webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btncerrar"]').click()
>      14 time.sleep(5)
> ---> 15 webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Préstamo Coche Nuevo').click()
>      16 webdriver.save_screenshot('test1.png')
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
> ```
>
> in find_element_by_link_text(self, link_text)
>           426             element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In')
>           427         """
>       --> 428         return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
>           429 
>           430     def find_elements_by_link_text(self, text):
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
> ```
>
> in find_element(self, by, value)
>           976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
>           977             'using': by,
>       --> 978             'value': value})['value']
>           979 
>           980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py
> ```
>
> in execute(self, driver_command, params)
>           319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
>           320         if response:
>       --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>           322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
>           323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py
> ```
>
> in check_response(self, response)
>           240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
>           241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>       --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>           243 
>           244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> ```
> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Préstamo Coche Nuevo"}
>   (Session info: headless chrome=72.0.3626.121)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.121,platform=Linux 4.14.79+ x86_64)
> ```

Comment: Your error comes from code `webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href*='prestamos/prestamo-Coche Nuevo']")`, but we can't see this code in your given code.  Please confirm your given code is correct.

Comment: I updated my question :)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: If you read the link you would see that screenshots of code are not allowed and why. Please remove the screenshot of HTML and replace it with the actual text of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply grab that url and get to it. Also, worth noting that you have a base url you can simply add the hyphenated search string to i.e. `financiar-viaje` on to base of https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/financiacion-coche.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
url =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[href*='financiar-viaje']"))).get_attribute('href')
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: It's working. I have another question: how do I get the same result from this link? Https://www.cofidis.es/es

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, just stepping in to meeting. Will update for you after.

Comment: I have two other very important questions for me. 

If you have time to see, I would be very grateful.

Here are the links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099298/unable-to-locate-element-selenium-webdriver/55125742#55125742

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119878/click-a-partial-div-link-using-python-selenium/55120424?noredirect=1#comment96989521_55120424

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to click on the link

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ei_tpl_navertical li>a[data='16736']").click()
```

Use implicit/explicit wait to make sure your element is ready to interact. in your case :

```
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/financiacion-coche.html"
webdriver.get(url)
webdriver.implicitlyWait(20)
webdriver.find_element_by_id('btncerrar').click()
time.sleep(5)
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ei_tpl_navertical li>a[data='16736']").click()
webdriver.save_screenshot('test1.png')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have already accepted an answer, and I do not have enough point for up vote your answer.

Comment: Np. glad to here :)

Comment: I have two other very important questions for me. 

If you have time to see, I would be very grateful.

Here are the links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099298/unable-to-locate-element-selenium-webdriver/55125742#55125742

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119878/click-a-partial-div-link-using-python-selenium/55120424?noredirect=1#comment96989521_55120424